# Connected to wi-fi but no network

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

My wi-fi router suddenly stopped working, and I can't get it to work. My provider had issues in my area, but they settled, and after that wi-fi is not working anymore.

I have a following setup: modem where is plugged cable from provider, and wi-fi router which is connected to modem.

If I connect with modem directly, via LAN cable, it's working fine. But if I try to connect via wi-fi, it does connect, but I can't open any page. If I connect to wi-fi router using LAN, it's not working either.

I can connect to other wi-fi (at friend's), so it's not due my laptop. Also, it's not working on phone, so it got to be something with wi-fi.

I tried to reset it to factory settings, but it didn't help.
Model is TP-LINK TL-WR-740n

I'm using gnome 3.

Here's what I got when run route -n, if it gives more light on this.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

Any help in troubleshooting this is greatly appreciated.

Status page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFWcp.png

Comment: Is the router you have issues with a dual-band unit, running at 5GHz by any chance? If your laptop only handles 2.4 GHz that may explain a few things. That could explain why your phone won't connect either. Just a thought... - Forget that, your updated Q puts a different slant on things...

Comment: It's 2.4 hHZ. Everything worked fine, untill yesterday. Then our provider has issues in our area, and after that wi-fi stopped working.

Comment: If you factory reset the router, you will need to set it up again. Follow the manufacturer instructions to do so and you should be all set unless it is defective. Give us some more details about the router so we can help you.

Comment: I set it up again, but it's not working. Just let me know what you need to know, I'm really a noob, so I don't really know what info to give either.

Comment: The fact your provider had issues in the area should be in your question. That is an important detail.

Comment: ok, didn't know that, since it's working now, only the wi-fi is giving a headache. I updated it.

Comment: So, to clarify, you *can* connect your router wirelessly, but you've no internet access? This would point to a communication issue between the modem and the router. You need to connect to it and login to the configuration page (which will be 192.168.0.1 or something very similar). Then you need to find the status page which will show details regarding the current connection status. The important info you need will be the WAN/external IP address (which will be a very different set of numbers, 80.15.2.65 for example). I suspect it will show 0.0.0.0 as your WAN address.

Comment: Also check your DNS address(es) in the router. Again, if it's having issues connecting to your modem they will probably come back as 0.0.0.0...

Comment: here's the screenshot, http://i.imgur.com/U3Yxd7b.png, it does show address.